# How to do do HtmlTextWriter.WriteAttribute with a single quote?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, htmlwriter

I'm writing a control to support HTML5 video. The type attribute has to specify the codec as well. Some examples show: `type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'`. When I'm writing the codec with the `HtmlWriter`, it flushes `type="video/mp4; codecs=&quot;avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2&quot;"`. So far so good, but my iPhone and iPad browsers refuse to work with the `&quot;`.

I'm using a `WriteAttribute`. How can I accomplish the writing of **single quoted** attributes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to do just the opposite: output the attribute in the HtmlWriter standard way (double quotes) and just embed your codecs option within a couple of single quotes. That should make the trick here.

Comment: Brilliant! Works like a charm.

Comment: Glad to have been helpful to you. ;)